# checking if key's already in dictionary with try except

Tags: python

I'm using a dictionary to count how many times different items appear in a dataset. In the **init** of the class, I create the property as a dictionary like this

```
self.number_found = {}
```

The first time I find any particular item, I would get a KeyError if I try to do this because the item isn't in the dictionary yet

```
self.number_found[item] = 1
```

so I ended up creating a function that checks if an entry is already in the dictionary and if not, adds it for the first time

```
 def _count_occurrences(self, item):

    try:
        #this checks to see if the item's already in the dict
        self.number_found[item] = self.number_found[item] + 1
        x = self.number_found[item] 
    except KeyError:
        x = 1
        #this adds an item if not in the dict
        self.number_found[item] = x
        return x
```

However, this is not working as intended if I find a second occurrence of an item in a dataset.

Let's say there are two 'elephant' in my dataset. When I print `self.number_found` to the console this is what I get

```
{'elephant': 1}
{'elephant': None}
```

and I get this error when adding the second occurrence

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Question: what's the right way to check if the key's already in the dictionary (with an explanation as to why the `1` is changing to a `None`)

Comment: Is your return x statement indented correctly?

Comment: That is what the [```get```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method is for: ```d[item] = d.get(item, 0)```.  [```collections.Counter```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) might be of help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

self.number_found = defaultdict(int)
```

The first time an item is accessed, its value will take a default of `0`

A `None` is returned because you're not *returning* anything in your `try` branch

Comment: thank you, can you explain why the 1 changed to None (as requested in the OP)

Answer (score 2):

The return at the end of the except block must be moved out.  That way, x is returned for both cases

```
class C(object):
     def __init__(self):
        self.number_found = {}

     def _count_occurrences(self, item):
        try:
            #this checks to see if the item's already in the dict
            self.number_found[item] = self.number_found[item] + 1
            x = self.number_found[item] 
        except KeyError:
            x = 1
            #this adds an item if not in the dict
            self.number_found[item] = x
        return x

c = C()

r = c._count_occurrences('elephant')
print r
print c.number_found
r = c._count_occurrences('elephant')
print r
print c.number_found
```

Here is a test run first with outdented return, then with it where you have it in your OP:

```
jcg@jcg:~/code/python/stack_overflow$ python number_found.py
1
{'elephant': 1}
2
{'elephant': 2}
jcg@jcg:~/code/python/stack_overflow$ python number_found.py
1
{'elephant': 1}
None
{'elephant': 2}
```

As you can see, the second version returns None since there is no return from the _count_occurrences try block